# ASP.NET Page is constantly reloading in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've been doing some searches and have come up empty. When I search for the phrase, I usually end up getting people asking how to make a page constantly reload. I'm having the opposite problem.

The situation: I have two functionally identical sets of code ("testing" branch and "production" branch - merged to be identical only a week ago) running on either IIS Express or ASP.NET Dev Server. The only difference is the database they're calling (and I even set that back so they were calling the same database). Of course we've made a few changes here and there for debugging purposes, but not to where the code functions any differently.

The problem: We have one script, Products.aspx, that handles virtual pages (much like WordPress does), referred to as "categories" since its primary use is for displaying groups of products in our ecommerce software. On the testing branch, this page is reloaded at random intervals between instantly and a few seconds. It's not registered as a PostBack (the `if (!IsPostBack)` registers as `true` when stepping through).

While it's making these infinite calls, it is creating a new thread every time through the page. Chrome Developer Tools says "waiting" time is 1.5-2 minutes (1.7 minutes the last time), and `WebResource.axd` and `ScriptResource.axd` are continuing as "pending" for several minutes.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Some code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack && !IsCallback)
        LoadList();
}

private void LoadList()
{
    int categoryId = Http.PrmIntOrZero["CategoryId"];
    string search = Http.PrmOrEmpty["Search"];

    DataRow c = DBCategory.GetOrNull(categoryId);
    if (c == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/", true);
        return;
    }

    TitleC.Text = (string)c["Name"];
    Description.Text = System.Convert.ToString(c["Description"]);
}
```

Note: Http.PrmIntOrZero is simply a method of calling the querystring with a shorter line.

EDIT 2: I went ahead and committed it up to a live environment as-is and it works just fine. I can't explain it, but it must have to do with Visual Studio's debugging process on that particular dev server, only it occurred in IIS Express as well...

Comment: Is it posting back without an user intervention?  I.e. On its own?

Comment: (!Page.IsPostBack && !Page.IsCallback) ?

Comment: Can you post some sample code for your products.aspx page?

Comment: @davenewza Yes, without user intervention, both before and after the page content finally loads.

Comment: @AnnArbor87 IsCallBack is also false.

Comment: Can you post the code? any Page_Load events?

Comment: I can think of two ways to make the page behave the way you describe (reload, not postback). One - by using "refresh" meta-directive (http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/meta.http-equiv.refresh.html), two - by executing "window.location.href = window.location.href;" javascript. How either of this can happen without you knowing - I cannot say.

Comment: @Igor I know, we've been unable to explain it as well. However, it was thought to have to do with the URL Rewrite, but that's not different and it doesn't hit it more than the first time. However, I suspect it has to do with the .axd resources not loading somehow..

Comment: @AnnArbor87 I posted up the Page_Load and the extent of the LoadList() method that gets executed.

Comment: the line that says "Response.Redirect("~/", true);" looks pretty suspicious.  It will do a round-trip to the client, which will load the default page (no post-back) with no querystring (null).  Under those conditions, would you expect your DB call to return a null?  Maybe there is an error in the DB call and it is returning a null.  Is there any error handling in the DB call or logs that you can check?

Comment: @tgolisch The DB call will return null if the page they try to browse to doesn't exist. For example, the page I'm testing with is /catalog/privacy-policy.aspx where 'privacy-policy' is the label in the database. If a user tries to access /catalog/asdfg.aspx the DB call will return null because there's no entry in the DB. This non-existent value forces a redirect to the home page.

Comment: I appreciate the help from everyone, or at least the ideas. The question's not answered since it works perfectly (and, more importantly, quickly) in a "live" environment (testing.domain.com) and not locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out we had a control that I didn't know about (I inherited the project from a previous developer) that was causing this.

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = this.ImageUrl;
        if (this.TemplateImageUrl != null)
        {
            text = this.TemplateImageUrl;
        }
        if (this.LoadedImageUrl != text)
        {
            Uri requestUri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url, base.ResolveClientUrl(text));
            try
            {
                using (WebResponse response = WebRequest.Create(requestUri).GetResponse())
                {
                    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(response.GetResponseStream());
                    this.Width = image.Width;
                    this.Height = image.Height;
                    this.LoadedImageUrl = text;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
```

The problem was the `base.OnPreReender(e);` was calling itself over and over.

Answer (score 0):

The line that says `Response.Redirect("~/", true);` is the culprit.

It will send a 302 to the browser to the root page. Since you mention this page handles virtual pages, I suppose it also handles a request to `"/"`. When the page is loaded again, you probably don't get a record from the database again and it redirects again. This will obviously continue endlessly.

Note: A 302 browser-redirect will NOT be recognized by ASP.NET as a postback so that `if`-clause is not protecting your page from getting into a loop.

The difference you're seeing in response time, is probably because there are various pending requests and sometimes the thread pool is used up and it has to wait for a few requests to finish.

Comment: Ordinarily that would be true, but the `/catalog/*.aspx` section is set up in the Rewrite module so that any other URL goes to where it's supposed to. So `"/"` physically goes to Default.aspx and is not directed at this page.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint there and check if at least if that's the reason it's reloading all the time? Maybe locally you have different rewrite rules

Comment: I have set a breakpoint there, yes. Every time it reloads `c` is not `null` so it never hits the redirect. When I load `/` or `/Default.aspx` it never hits the redirect.

Comment: Hm, OK, than it's not that. Another way of debugging this I can suggest is using HttpFiddler and inspect the requests. If I'm not mistaken HttpFiddler has an option to check what triggered the request.

Comment: Thanks, Kenneth. I'll check it out. Where it works perfectly (in the same code) on another "website" in VS, I'm inclined to think that something with that particular instance of the dev server is messed up. I'll try a couple more things and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

code line  DataRow c = DBCategory.GetOrNull(categoryId); is getting null values all the times so make sure you have data in your database.

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack && !IsCallback)
            LoadList();
    }

    private void LoadList()
    {
        int categoryId = Http.PrmIntOrZero["CategoryId"];
        string search = Http.PrmOrEmpty["Search"];

        DataRow c = DBCategory.GetOrNull(categoryId);
        if (c == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/", true);
            return;
        }

        TitleC.Text = (string)c["Name"];
        Description.Text = System.Convert.ToString(c["Description"]);
    }
```

Comment: I've already said it does not have a null value when I step through it. Or it would redirect to the home page (which it does perfectly fine). So that's not the problem. See, I get different results on the **same** code running on different dev server instances (from the same database).